# PHP, MYSQL, HTML table with tablesorter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, tablesorter

Trying to add [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) added to a page I am creating.  I know very little of jquery, so I'm guessing that's where my fault is.  I've added the required code in the `<head>` area of my page, and made the necessary changes to my table.  My table still renders as it would with just HTML.  Ideas?

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Inventory</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){ $("table").tablesorter(); });
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db_name");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$query = "SELECT 
            products.name,
            products.sku,
            inventory.quantityfry,
            inventory.quantityjuv,
            inventory.quantityadult,
            inventory.notes,
            inventory.location,
            inventory.owner
          FROM 
            products
          INNER JOIN 
            inventory
          ON
            products.sku=inventory.sku";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
echo "<table border='1' id='table' class='tablesorter'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Species</th>
<th>SKU</th>
<th>Fry Count</th>
<th>Juvie Count</th>
<th>Adult Count</th>
<th>Notes</th>
<th>Location</th>
<th>Owner</th>

</tr>
</thead>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tbody>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['sku'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['quantityfry'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['quantityjuv'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['quantityadult'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['location'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['owner'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";    
}

mysqli_free_result($result);

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>     
 </body>



</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're adding a tbody tag for every row

Comment: try http://datatables.net/ is easy to integrate

Comment: You probably want `$('#table').datasorter()` as well. NO idea if datasorter wants a specific element, or will attach itself to ALL tables being returned by `$('table')`.

Comment: Why not just sort it right at the source?

Comment: Place `echo "<tbody>"; echo "<tr>";` and `echo "</tr>"; echo "</tbody>";` outside your `while` loop.

Comment: Moving tbody and tr outside of the while loop broke the table.  I moved tr back in the loop, leaving tbody outside the loop and it formats the HTML table fine, but doesn't load the tablesorter.  I've also set `$('#table').tablesorter()`, but that didn't change anything either.  Guess I can take a look at that datatables.

Comment: Why don't you just SORT right in your query instead. I say this because, what if a user has JS disabled?

Comment: I don't want to sort right in the query because there will be times where a different sort will be desired.  I've put this on pause and am playing around with ajaxCRUD, since it will allow me to still use my MySQL DB, but edit fields right in a browser. Much more desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. Don't link directly to tablesorter at tablesorter.com - make a copy to your own server, or use a copy at a CDN (this is of my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/) at [cdnjs.com](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.tablesorter/)).
2. Include a `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your HTML otherwise IE will change into quirks mode and pretty much make your site look bad.
3. As @MikeB mentioned, the above code wraps every row in a `tbody`, correct the code as follows (this is just a snippet):

   ```
   echo "<table border='1' id='table' class='tablesorter'>
   <thead>
   <tr>
   <th>Species</th>
   <th>SKU</th>
   <th>Fry Count</th>
   <th>Juvie Count</th>
   <th>Adult Count</th>
   <th>Notes</th>
   <th>Location</th>
   <th>Owner</th>

   </tr>
   </thead><tbody>";

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['sku'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['quantityfry'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['quantityjuv'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['quantityadult'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['location'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['owner'] . "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";

   }

   mysqli_free_result($result);

   echo "</tbody></table>";
   ```